# Recursive method for recommending friends

Tags: java

I am trying to write a recursive method to recommend friends as written here

> We’ll take the approach of
>   recommending all of our friends’ friends and our friends’ friends’ friends, and so on.
>   This is a perfect opportunity to use recursion – we can create a
>   getRecommendations method that takes a FacebookUser as an argument. The
>   method should return an ArrayList that contains all of the friends of the
>   FacebookUser that is passed into it plus the result of calling the same
>   getRecommendations method on all of that FacebookUser’s friends. Be careful not to add anyone to the list of recommendations if they are already on it – that could lead to an infinite loop.

My code so far is:

```
ArrayList<FacebookUser> getRecommendations(FacebookUser example) {
    for (FacebookUser u : example.getFriends()) {
        if (recommendations.contains(u)) {
            return recommendations;
        } else {
            recommendations.add(u);
            for (FacebookUser a : recommendations) {
                getRecommendations(a);
            }
        }
    }
    return recommendations;
}
```

`recommendations` is an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<FacebookUser> recommendations = new ArrayList<>();
```

And my `getFriends()` method is here:

```
ArrayList<FacebookUser> getFriends() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<FacebookUser> clone = (ArrayList<FacebookUser>) friends
            .clone();
    return clone;
}
```

Can someone give me a correct `getRecommendations()` method to use or point out what is wrong with my method?

Comment: I reverted it? I don't understand what you're talking about

Comment: I was trying to add more info, I think I edited it the same time you did, sorry.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob here. Thanks for fixing my post anyway

Comment: The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) is very helpful. You can spend some time there, if you like :). Btw: I deleted my old comments, they are not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the else branch you don't need to call the recursive function again and again for **all** users in recommendations. Instead just call it for the newly found user that you just added to the recommendation list, like this:

```
else {
    recommendations.add(u);
    getRecommendations(u);
}
```

otherwise you will end up with an infinite loop as the text you included explains.

Comment: Wow, that helped a lot. Thank you! :)